# How can I map a SignalR payload to an TypeScript class?

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

We are using signalR to request the used cpu and ram from the server:

```
// create connection
let hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/MyUrl").build();

// response message
hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (pMessage: string) => {

  // convert to json
  let lObj = JSON.parse(pMessage);
  let lServerResources = new ServerResources(lObj.cpu, lObj.ram);

  // do something with this result [...]
});
```

Here is the simple ServerResources class:

```
// simple data class
export class ServerResources
{
  constructor(public cpu: string, public ram: string)
  {  }
}
```

**Problem:** The `pMessage` parameter contains a json string as value like: `'{"cpu":"72%","ram":"2540MB"}'` which we need to convert to an javascript object and after that, map to the `ServerResources` class. We want to save these two steps. We want to get an `ServerResources`-object directly.

We tried the following. But it is still a string:

```
hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (pMessage: ServerResources) => {
    // [...]
}
```

Anyhow Angular maps the payload of an http-request by generics:

```
this.http.get<ServerResources>("MyUrl").pipe( [...] );
```

**Question:** How can we map the singnalR payload automatically to a typescript class?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a general function to [hydrate TypeScript classes from JSON](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2018/11/create-and-hydrate-a-typescript-class-from-json/):

```
function hydrate<T>(constr: { new(...args: any[]): T }, data: string, strictMode: boolean = true, ...args: any[]): T {
    const obj = JSON.parse(data);
    const instance = new constr(...args);

    for (let key in obj) {
        if (!strictMode || instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            instance[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Here is an example using it in your specific case (I added a method to the class for illustration):

```
class ServerResources {
  constructor(public cpu: string, public ram: string)
  { }

  getSomething() {
    alert(this.cpu + ' ' + this.ram)
  }
}

const data = `{ "cpu": "SUPER-8", "ram": "FAST-SHEEP"}`;

const example = hydrate(ServerResources, data, false);

example.getSomething();
```

Comment: I already know this as an 'automapper' which is well known for ajax-Requests in JavaScript. I would prefer a built-in solution if exists. Nevertheless thank you for your contribution.

Comment: There's no one-step solution as parsing JSON just gives you a plain data object. You either need to manually map, or auto-map to push that data into your more intelligent object.